# vb if condition on items and price from database

Tags: vb.net

I actually have a Access database where i have a table called "tblfreight" and two column is there (items and Price)

And I want to auto show the Price when I choose Items.

There is two Textbox:   "txtitems" and "txtprice"

I want to be like this....

```
If txtitems.text = select from tblfreight and column items Then

txtprice.text = select from tblfreight and column Price

Else txtprice.text=0 (Zero)
```

Comment: What language is that?

Answer (score 1):

You need to query your DB first..

Select * from tblfreight  - will get you your data you need.

Then you need to put this data somewhere. You can use a combobox for this. Once you have your combobox filled with your data you then can set the price into a label or textbox easily.

You can use the combobox selected index changed event...

Inside the changed event something like this would work...

```
textprice.text = Combobox.selecteditem.value
```

This will give you a great start, that's why this answer just gives you the steps and not the full code.